# Load devel configuration using a command in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.6

I have a command in Symfony2 and I want to be able to read the devel config from `config_dev.yml`

I'm trying to retrieve the config in the command `execute` method like this:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $this->getContainer()->getParameter('parse');
}
```

But when I execute the command:

```
$ php app/console acme:test
```

It gives me the following error message:

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "acme"

Data in `config_dev.yml` that I want to retrieve:

```
acme:
    foo:    "bar"
```

The command extends `containerAwareCommand`:

```
class AcmeCommand extends containerAwareCommand
```

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

**Update**

Configuration tree example:

> // src/Acme/ApiBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php

```
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('acme');

    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->scalarNode('foo')->end()
        ->end() 
    ;

    return $treeBuilder;
}
```

Extension example:

> // src/Acme/ApiBundle/DependencyInjection/AcmeApiExtension.php

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
    $container->setParameter('acme', $config);

    $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.xml');
```

config_dev.yml example:

```
...
acme:
    foo: "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the configuration tree like [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html)?

Comment: I don't know how to represent a configuration tree that includes both `config.yml` and `config_dev.yml` ( I can make it work only defining data in `config.yml`, but I don't know how to include also `config_dev.yml` if I have data defined also there)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just interested in storing and retrieving arbitrary data from a config file, then you should store it in `parameters.yml`, rather than `config_dev.yml`.

Config entries in `parameters.yml` are allowed to be free-form, as long as they are below the `parameters:` key, whereas entires in `config*.yml` files need to conform to a structure defined in your bundle configuration.

You should define the keys for data you want to store in `parameters.yml.dist` first, however.

Comment: I see what you mean, I've tried it and it works fine. But I would rather like to execute the command with the `--env=<environment>` option, in order to dynamically load config from the corresponding `config_<environment>.yml` file.